# Create <Header></Header> widget using react js in other react project

Tags: reactjs, widget, web-component

How can i create Header project in react and want to share the same to other projects without npm?

Is there any way I can share script and selector like `<Header></Header>` and they can use the same?

I have tried so many things but cann't able to share with other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are talking about reusing Header component in some other project. I suggest you to take a look at [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) . You can simply add that same component inside the new application and then use it there.

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thanks for reply, I am asking how to create WebComponent using react and use other react  project by adding script and selector only

Comment: I have to give     <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5000/static/js/bundle.js"></script> and <header></header> only to other team member to include. As we are trying to create header as independent project

Comment: Loading a script and using ``<header></header>`` won't work for multiple reasons. 1: ``header`` is an [existing standard HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header).  2. ``<Header>`` is React/React notation, it is not a valid W3C Custom Element/Web Component for the Browser. For dynamically loading React components see: https://alligator.io/react/loading-components-dynamically-hooks/ React only matches 71% with the W3C standards Custom Elements API, see React section at: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/ where React fails to match the W3C standard.

Comment: Hi Danny, I want to webComponent created using reactjs in other project. I don't know to use web component of one app to another. I can change selector <app-header> also

Comment: **React Components** are not **W3C standard Web Components**; they are totally different technologies. So you can only use React Components in *another* React project.. You can use W3C Components IN React... but that is the 71% match.. needs more of your work/time in React to make it work

Comment: So how to share component of one project/app to another project. Any link? I also want to share props also like <app-header title="title"></app-header> Please suggest as soon as possible